# The meaning of "Konsequenz aus etwas ziehen"

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

The academic book I`m using has translated this part of a sentence

> Konsequenz aus etwas ziehen

as

> draw the consequences from something

and I can't really relate what does it mean ?

I have searched for the English translation of this and I came by a thread saying the English expression is wrong.

So I am stuck on getting the meaning in both languages.

So if someone can introduce an explanation of the German expression in any language (German/English), it would help.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do need to understand, what "Konsequenz aus etwas ziehen" in German means so that you can translate it yourself into english? Or do you need the understanding in German _and_ a good translation into English? If "a thread" says this (which? the German or the English?) is wrong - did it elaborate what is wrong?

Comment: i don't know 
but i tried to correct my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Konsequenzen aus etwas ziehen" means to "take consequences" or sometimes to "draw conclusions". What is meant: An insight or perhaps an action resulting from this insight.

My employer hasn't paid me for three months now. So I take the consequences and quit.